# How to Srot rdd inner list element in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have created A Rdd's like below

```
rdd=sc.parallelize([['A','C','B'], ['D','A','B','C'], ['C','B'],['B']])
```

I want to sort inner list elements. for example first element inside rdd is `['A','C','B']`,but I want to sort like `['A','B','C']`

my expected output is:

```
 [['A','B','C'], ['A','B','C','D'], ['B','C'],['B']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier and usually more efficient (since spark optimizer works on dataframes whereas you need to optimize rdds yourself) to work with dataframes rather than rdds:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df=spark.createDataFrame([[['A','C','B']], [['D','A','B','C']], [['C','B']],[['B']]],['l'])
df.show()
+------------+
|           l|
+------------+
|   [A, C, B]|
|[D, A, B, C]|
|      [C, B]|
|         [B]|
+------------+

df.withColumn('l',sort_array('l')).show()
+------------+
|           l|
+------------+
|   [A, B, C]|
|[A, B, C, D]|
|      [B, C]|
|         [B]|
+------------+
```

if you still want an rdd you can always

```
rdd=df.withColumn('l',sort_array('l')).rdd
```

Comment: @Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz ,Thanks for reply,as you said DF is best. as per my requirement i have to use only RDD.

Answer (score 1):

i've created the `RDD` as you mentioned in the question.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([['A','C','B','A'], ['D','A','B','C'], ['C','B'],['B']])
```

You can sort the individual elements in `rdd` using `sorted` function.

```
rdd.map(lambda x: sorted(x)).collect()
[['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'C'], ['B']]
```

Comment: The answer posted by @mehrdad-pedramfar will work efficiently for python lists, but the question was related to spark rdd's.

Comment: @sai, as I mentioned in my answer using dataframes, is more optimized - using this approach spark will need to push all the data from scala to python to do the sorting (since it is running a black-box (for it) python code whereas using the built in udf the sorting will occur on the Scala side and will be optimized with any other manipulations you have on the data

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz, of course, your approach is way more optimized than mine (i have mentioned that in my comment in your answer), but the question was related to spark `rdd`'s .

Comment: I just explained the diff to @sai/future viewers the diff. It isn't meant as a criticism of your solution. Datasets are more efficient both in memory and performance https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html and this can be a big diff on things that aren't toy examples